# Configuring Cassandra deployments in NAT environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Here is one deployment scenario wherein NAT exists between DC boundaries, following are the requirements:

Cassandra Version: 2.1.13

1. There are 2 DCs, two Cassandra nodes (dc1:node1 & dc2:node3) across DCs should communicate across NAT boundaries using public IP.
2. One of the DC which is behind NAT has 2 Cassandra nodes (dc1:node1 and dc1:node2) and both them should communicate within NAT using private IP.
3. All these 3 nodes (dc1:node1, dc1:node2 & dc2:node3) should form a ring and communicate with each other.

Looked into seeds, listen_address, broadcast_address & broadcast_rpc_address.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

If there are public IPs used in broadcast_address and seeds then across DC & NAT communication works, however the nodes which are within NAT not able to detect each other.

If there are private IPs used in broadcast_address and seeds then within DC & NAT communication works, however the nodes across DC & NAT not able to detect each other.

Looked into Ec2MultiRegionSnitch but that will not work for premise deployments: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c.html#architectureSnitchEC2MultiRegion_c__other-settings

**What configuration settings will be required to achieve above 3 requirements?**

Answer (score 3):

Use gossiping property file snitch, set public ip as broadcast_address and private ip as listen_address. They will use the listen_address in same DC and broadcast address if in other DC.

Comment: Yeah, made these changes but these are not working for the nodes within DC & NAT. Across DC & NAT nodes are able to communicate correctly.

Comment: might wanna check firewall, `nc -z {private ip of other in dc} 7000` to test connectivity. `netstat -anp | grep 7000` to see what its listening on

Comment: Hi Chris, how the node3 which is outside NAT will be able to communicate with private ip of node1 which is behind NAT?  But node3 would be able to communicate with only public ip of node 1,and then NAT will translate public to private IP, right?

Comment: Settings made with seeds=public address, listen_address=private and broadcast_address=public.
With these settings across all 3 nodes:
dc1:node1 & dc2:node3 works but dc1:node1 and dc1:node2 doesn't, is it because of seeds have public address within DC behind NAT might nor work?

One of the observation to check listen on dc1:node1, private IP is listed: 
node1# netstat -anp | grep -E "(7001)"
tcp        0      0 dc1:node1_privateIP:7001            0.0.0.0:*                     LISTEN      9999/java

Can dc1:node2 establish connection with dc1:node1_publicIP?

Comment: if in same DC as one of seeds use its private not public

Answer (score 0):

Settings made with seeds=public address, listen_address=private and broadcast_address=public. 
With these settings made on all 3 nodes:

- dc1:node1 & dc2:node3 works but
- dc1:node1 and dc1:node2 doesn't

Is it because of seeds have public address within DC behind NAT might nor work?

One of the observation to check listen on dc1:node1, private IP is listed:

```
node1# netstat -anp | grep -E "(7001)" 
tcp 0 0 dc1:node1_privateIP:7001 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9999/java
```

Can dc1:node2 establish connection with dc1:node1_publicIP? 
Is this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9748 related here or will be only applicable in case of multiple NICS and not NAT environment?